# Batch GET in sharepoint server 2013 to implement paging

Tags: 2013, rest, paging, batch

I would like to implement paging in sharepoint 2013, so I would like to get current list item count first, then do the paging so I can tell users: 1-30 of 400 items, in my paging.

Can I do this in batching so i make a request first to get item count, then get top 30 items in my list in the same request?

Answer (score 3):

To implemente pagination on this rest api is not that simple, you need to do some tweaks.

Default URL - "/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StudentsList')/items?&$top=5";

For this go through the response of first REST Ajax call. If you read each property carefully you will get answer for pagination. Properly "__next" is nothing but the REST url for next page :). Is it simple? Yes. So use "data.d.__next" to get next page items. REST service always returns this property whenever there is possible next set of items otherwise returns null.

Below is what url you will get

[image]

To get total count you need to make /itemCount rest call.

Adjust your logic to divide data in pagination and use _next attribute to get next set of data.

[Ref link](http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-how-to-implement.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know all of this. I am asking about a way to make the 2 calls in the same request. I know __next and itemCount. Is there a way to do both of them in the same request? thanks

Comment: no...there is no way to do this in same request using rest api....also you should edit your question with what things you have tried..it helps others for answering..

Comment: I didn't have to state what I tried as it's a different question i am saying i need to batch. i didn't expect an answer to a different question. thank you